# Sending a POST request to google forms ( Python )

Tags: python, python-requests, google-forms

I created a google form, here's the link: https://forms.gle/Z1WeuByQUkRAVT9h9

Its only work when disabling the "Response receipts" option.
How can I solve this?

This is my code :

```
import requests

def send(code,command):
    pload = {"emailAddress": "bodateg647@aregods.com",
             "entry.809261186": code,
             "entry.957647657": command
         }
    response = requests.post('https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSdnXiWB-1Bezs14w1ljZi4wFsFylj1F5UdXE68A59E__ah8ig/formResponse',data = pload)

send('A012','On')
```

Comment: "Its only work" -- what happens otherwise?

Comment: @TimRoberts Couldn't get any responses. The goal is form should be filled with python request and a copy should be sent to the specified gmail address.

Comment: What led you to believe that would work?  There are a bunch of type=hidden fields that you're not sending.  There's a formal Google API for Forms,  Have you checked that out?